# Border-radius inside border bug in Opera

Tags: opera, css

I have a problem with displaying a block with top/bottom border and border-radius. Don't know why an inside radius appears within a border.. Please, take look at the screenshot & code below..

http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/3074/scrren1.jpg

```
<section id="block">
   <div class="block-header"><h1>Block</h1></div>
</section>
#block {width:1000px; height:329px; position:relative; border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px; -webkit-border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;}  
#block .block-header { position:absolute; right:0px; top: 0; border-top:10px solid #81a32b; width:500px; border-radius:0px 4px 0px 0px; -webkit-border-radius:0px 4px 0px 0px; }
```

Do u know any solution to this problem?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/325nH/)

Comment: better post the html and css counterparts then the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Opera the height is directly related to the rounding you are trying to achieve

Css

```
border-top:10px solid #81a32b; 
border-radius:0px 10px 0px 0px;
```

Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/325nH/2/

you have declared:

```
border-top:10px solid #81a32b; 
border-radius:0px 4px 0px 0px;
```

so you are 6px short that are filled by Opera with white space